# Is there any Web Site where i can translate W3-theme colors to RGB?

Tags: css, rgb

For example i want to translate this color `w3-theme-d1` (a type of grey) to RGB code.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: Then tell me how to traslate it, in a logic way.

Answer (score -1):

W3.CSS is a CSS created by w3schools

w3-theme-d1 is defined in the file https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-dark-grey.css

In that file, it was defined as:

```
.w3-theme-d1 {color:#fff !important; background-color:#575757 !important}
```